# How to get the hover grey color the right size

Tags: html, css

Having spent considerable time on this menu I am still having problems lining it all up the way I would like it, here is my menu code and hopefully some will be able to help.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="bandmenu">
   <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="song-list.html">Song List</a></li>
      <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
      <li><a href="shows.html">Shows</a></li>
      <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="comments.html">Comments</a></li>
      <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bandmenu {
    padding-top: 134px;
    width: 100%;
}

#bandmenu .nav{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1px;
}

#bandmenu .nav li{
    display: inline;
    height: 2px;
}

#bandmenu .nav a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#bandmenu .nav a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: darkgray;
}
```

Comment: i am unsure of the question. what is the problem here?

Comment: try to provide a snippet (Ctrl+M), it would be usefull to help you

Comment: When i place the mouse over the menu items the hover color block is to big, it should fit within the top line and bottom line.

Comment: There are no top lines or bottom lines in your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment I guess you want like [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/11dsoe4b/)

You need to modify the CSS like this:

```
#bandmenu .nav a{
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0 15px;
   height: 15px;
   line-height: 15px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 16px;        
}
```

Due to the fact that you defined a padding to the top and to the bottom you will get a large grey hover area. You need to remove it, set the height and place the text in the center of the height.

Comment: Thank you, it was simple but then i didn't realize i didn't need the top padding.